# How to perform some action on a node after it is loaded in JavaScript in Odoo?

Tags: javascript, xml, odoo, odoo-10

I made a new widget for a `Char` field. I'm inheriting its template from the original one of `Char`:

```
<t t-name="FieldRed" t-extend="FieldChar">
    <t t-jquery="input" t-operation="attributes">
        <attribute name="id">barcode_input</attribute>
        <attribute name="class">o_form_input bg-red</attribute>
    </t>
</t>
```

Then, I'm only trying to fill in the field with some text when it is loaded (I know I can do that without using JavaScript but I need to manage this to start with my actual purpose). So, I did this:

```
var FieldRed = widget.FieldChar.extend({
    template: 'FieldRed',
    events: _.extend({}, widget.FieldChar.prototype.events, {
        'load': 'on_load',
        'ready': 'on_ready',
        'keypress': 'on_keypress',
    }),

    init: function (field_manager, node) {
        console.log('INIT');
        this._super(field_manager, node);
        this.$el.parent().find('input').val('INIT');
    },

    on_load: function (e) {
        console.log('LOAD');
        this.$el.parent().find('input').val('LOAD');
    },

    on_ready: function (e) {
        console.log('READY');
        this.$el.parent().find('input').val('READY');
    },

    on_keypress: function (e) {
        console.log('KEYPRESS');
        this.$el.parent().find('input').val('KEYPRESS');
    },
})
```

First of all, I expected to find the `input` element in `this.$el`, but it is in `this.$el.parent()`, is that because of the `input` element is declared in the original template?

And my main question: I can fill in the `input` node text automatically on `keypress`, but the same line of code does not work in `init` method, neither `load` nor `ready` events. How can I fill in the text of the `input` node each time the user opens the form which contains the field with my widget?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can use the `start` method, which is also automatically called. This happens after the call of `init` and `willStart`, then the view is rendered and afterwards `start` is called. This is  well explained in the official documentation, in the Widget Lifecycle section:

https://www.odoo.com/documentation/11.0/reference/javascript_reference.html

> When the rendering is complete, the framework will automatically call
>   the start method. This is useful to perform some specialized
>   post-rendering work. For example, setting up a library.
>
> Must return a deferred to indicate when its work is done.

So I only had to inherit from the original `start` method and add my functionality:

```
start: function() {
    console.log('START');
    this._super.apply(this, arguments);
    this.$el.parent().find('input').val('START');
},
```